# Trying to run RSelenium (Windows 7/ Mac OS X)

Tags: java, r, web-scraping, rcurl, rselenium

I am trying to run RSelenium in both Windows 7 and Mac OS X. I have read through some simple how-to guides for RSelenium and when I repeat their code, RStudio throws the following warning/error messages:

```
checkForServer()
startServer()

Warning message:
running command '"java" -jar "C:/Users/TEMP/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/RSelenium/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar" -log "C:/Users/TEMP/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/RSelenium/bin/sellog.txt"' had status 127 

remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Undefined error in RCurl call.
Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts)) :
```

However, the Mac only trips at the error message and not the warning.

copied from OP's answer.. 
@hrbrmstr Here is the output from devtools::session_info().

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.473)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Los_Angeles         

Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version  date       source                             
 assertthat   0.1      2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 bitops     * 1.0-6    2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 caTools      1.17.1   2014-09-10 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 codetools    0.2-14   2015-07-15 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 colorspace   1.2-6    2015-03-11 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 curl         0.9.2    2015-08-08 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 DBI        * 0.3.1    2014-09-24 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 devtools   * 1.8.0    2015-05-09 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 digest       0.6.8    2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 dplyr      * 0.4.2    2015-06-16 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 ggplot2    * 1.0.1    2015-03-17 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 git2r        0.11.0   2015-08-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 gtable       0.1.2    2012-12-05 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 httr       * 1.0.0    2015-06-25 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 lubridate  * 1.3.3    2013-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 magrittr     1.5      2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 MASS         7.3-43   2015-07-16 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 memoise      0.2.1    2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 munsell      0.4.2    2013-07-11 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 plyr         1.8.3    2015-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 proto        0.3-10   2012-12-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 R6           2.1.1    2015-08-19 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 Rcpp         0.12.0   2015-07-25 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 RCurl      * 1.95-4.7 2015-06-30 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 reshape2     1.4.1    2014-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 rjson      * 0.2.15   2014-11-03 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 RJSONIO    * 1.3-0    2014-07-28 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 RMySQL     * 0.10.4   2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 RSelenium  * 1.3.6    2015-08-20 Github (ropensci/RSelenium@f597355)
 rversions    1.0.2    2015-07-13 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 rvest      * 0.2.0    2015-01-01 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 scales       0.2.5    2015-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 scrapeR    * 0.1.6    2010-02-03 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 stringi      0.5-5    2015-06-29 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 stringr      1.0.0    2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 XML        * 3.98-1.3 2015-06-30 CRAN (R 3.2.2) 
 xml2         0.1.1    2015-06-02 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `devtools::session_info()`? This worked fine on my OS X 10.10.5, R 3.2.2, RStudio daily setup.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I posted the output below.